# Performance of primitive vs. non-primitive data types in Drools

Tags: java, drools

I was wondering what would be the implications on performance and memory usage of using primitives compared to non-primitive data types in Drools.

In [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.CR2/drools-docs/html/ch08.html), it is stated:

> 8.8.6. A Note on Auto-boxing and Primitive Types Drools attempts to preserve numbers in their primitive or object wrapper form, so a
>   variable bound to an int primitive when used in a code block or
>   expression will no longer need manual unboxing; unlike Drools 3.0
>   where all primitives were autoboxed, requiring manual unboxing. A
>   variable bound to an object wrapper will remain as an object; the
>   existing JDK 1.5 and JDK 5 rules to handle auto-boxing and unboxing
>   apply in this case. When evaluating field constraints, the system
>   attempts to coerce one of the values into a comparable format; so a
>   primitive is comparable to an object wrapper.

Basically, in my rules, I have conditions such as:

```
$someObj : SomeObj( someIntOrIntegerField > 15 )
```

and accumulations as follows:

```
$total : Double() from accumulate (
                 SomeObj(
                    $someIntOrIntegerField : someIntOrIntegerField) over window:time( 1h ),
                 sum( $someIntOrIntegerField ) )
```

What I understand is that Drools delegates coercion to JVM and does not do any boxing/unboxing. Is this true? As I am racing against time in couple of milliseconds, I was wondering which would be faster:

```
int someIntOrIntegerField;
```

or

```
Integer someIntOrIntegerField;
```

Please note that my question is about if there's a boxing/unboxing which I am not aware of in Drools, and whether primitives or `Object`s would be faster and efficient(in terms of memory), again, limited to Drools. Otherwise, there's a good answer in general Java scope: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/203971

Comment: _Measure._ Primitive types rarely are slower. A wrapper type could only be faster if nothing is done with it, but shoving it around _and_ the primitive type would need wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one part of your question that is answerable is this:

> What I understand is that Drools delegates coercion to JVM and does not do any boxing/unboxing. Is this true?

No it is not true.  The JVM does not perform autoboxing / unboxing conversions.  It is the (source -> bytecode) compiler that is responsible for inserting calls to (for example) `Integer.valueOf(int)` and `Integer.intValue()` into the appropriate point in the bytecodes.  You can verify this by using `javap` to examine the ".class" files.

In the case of Drools, the the compiler produces ".class" files that have any necessary autoboxing / unboxing in the bytecodes.  I think that the documentation you have quoted actually means that the Drools compiler's strategy for autoboxing / unboxing has changed ... since Drools 3.0

Comment: Will the JVM do JIT compiling that might modify the boxing/unboxing behavior?

Comment: It won't modify the behavior.  It might do some optimizations ... but that is different.